# The program compiler won't let me use "else" in the last 2 cases and I can't see why

Tags: c#

I can't find why cases 2,3 wont let me use else for the category selection but it lets me use it in case 1. Where is it falling apart? What code needs editing?

I fixed the elses I think but I got a new error that I've never seen before control cannot fall through from one case label('case3:') to another. What does this mean?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum Numbers { standard = 1, express = 2, same = 3 };

    const int A = 1, B = 2;
    const int Y = 3, N = 4;
    static void Main()
    {

        double cost, LB;
        int Number_of_items;
        int myNumbers;
        char catagory;
        char surcharge = 'Y';

        Console.WriteLine("please enter the type of shiping you want");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1:standard shipping.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 2:express shipping.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 3:same day shipping.");

        myNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch ((Numbers)myNumbers)
        {
            case Numbers.standard:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing standerd shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                catagory = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                {
                    if (catagory == 'A')
                    {
                        Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                        Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        cost = 3 * Number_of_items;

                        Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                        surcharge = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        if (surcharge == 'Y')
                        {
                            cost = cost + 2.50;

                            Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}.", cost);
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}.", cost);


                    }
                    else
                        Console.Write("please enter the weight in pounds");
                    LB = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cost = 1.45 * LB;
                    Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                } surcharge = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (surcharge == 'Y')
                {
                    cost = cost + 2.50;

                    Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}.", cost);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}.", cost);

                break;


            case Numbers.express:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing Express Shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                catagory = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (catagory == 'A')
                {
                    Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                    Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cost = 4 * Number_of_items;
                    {
                        Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                        surcharge = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (surcharge == 'Y')
                        {
                            cost = cost + 5.00;

                            Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}.", cost);
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}.", cost);


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    {

                        Console.Write("please enter the weight in pounds");
                        LB = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        cost = 2.50 * LB;
                        Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                    }
                }

                surcharge = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (surcharge == 'Y')
                {
                    cost = cost + 5.00;

                    Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}.", cost);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}.", cost);
                break;





            case Numbers.same:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing Same Day Shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                catagory = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (catagory == 'A')
                {
                    Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                    Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cost = 5.50 * Number_of_items;

                    Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                    surcharge = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (surcharge == 'Y')
                    {
                        {
                            cost = cost + 8.00;

                            Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}.", cost);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}.", cost);
                    }


                }
                else
                {

                    {
                        Console.Write("please enter the weight in pounds");
                        LB = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        cost = 3.00 * LB;
                        surcharge = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                    }
                    if (surcharge == 'Y')
                    {
                        cost = cost + 8.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}.", cost);
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}.", cost);

                    break;
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

        }//End Main()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well there's some extra {'s in there from what I can see.... not sure why you're trying to scope those areas and it's kind of hard to read since your code is not formatted correctly.

Comment: You should correctly indent your code (eg, using Visual Studio's format option)

Comment: invalid expresion term 'else'

Comment: ...and *where* do you get that error? Not the line number, please. Where in the code above? Add a comment.

Comment: In Visual Studio, press Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D -- this will automatically reformat your code so you can see where the { } and ( ) line up (or not). If you don't like the results, use Undo (Ctrl-Z) to undo.

Comment: This is why, as a rule, we require braces around all clauses, even if they are one line.  A good use of stylecop, and avoids this kind of mess.

Comment: Check OP's question history. 3 questions on the same program. He's using Stackoverflow as his online debugging tool. Poor due diligence on his part. At least we got proof that the "cloud" works! :)

Comment: sorry im not trying to use this as a debugging tool im just geting errors that ive nvr seen before thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run your code through `Lindent` to fix the horrible formatting and it reported `unmatched else`. You have too many `else` statements in your code.:

```
indent: foo.c:93: Error:Unmatched 'else'
indent: foo.c:139: Error:Unmatched 'else'
indent: foo.c:164: Error:Unexpected end of file
```

(Yes, `indent(1)` is not intended for C#, but it works surprisingly well on most C-like languages, and in this case has pointed out at least two `else` statements that aren't properly matched. And don't worry about those specific line numbers -- this routine needs to be properly formatting and broken apart into smaller pieces -- trying to just bodge this together with a few correctly-placed `{}` isn't the right answer.)

Break apart your gigantic `main()` routine into smaller functions. (Your code duplicates the Alaska / Hawaii question *six* times -- that should be a separate routine right there. Maybe all yes / no questions should be handled through one routine: pass in the question and it'll do the prompt and return `true` or `false` for you.)

I strongly recommend using braces on your `else` clauses if you used them on your `if` clause:

This is fine:

```
if (foo)
    /* statement */
else
    /* single statement */
```

But if you *ever* need to use braces on the first block, then use them on the `else` block too:

```
if (foo) {
    /* stuff */
    /* more stuff */
} else {
    /* use those braces! */
    /* you will find reading your code far easier if you do */
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems here. The first is a couple of braces that shouldn't be there. i.e. these:

```
        catagory = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        {   // <------- THIS ONE
            if (catagory == 'A')
        // 
        // skipped code
        //

            Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
        } /* <------- THIS ONE */ surcharge = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (surcharge == 'Y')
```

The second problem (the one that is causing your *control cannot fall through* error) is the fact that the **break** statement for the Numbers.same case is inside a conditioned block of statements (in the else part of your `if (catagory == 'A')`). This means that it will be executed only when category is different from 'A', and not for every value of your variable. You just have to move the break after the brace.